# Get field Matrix field label inside template

Tags: templating

I have Matrix field containing block with various fields. How can I output into template label of single field?

Can I get type of that field? (for example - textfield, dropdown field, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do what you're looking for:

```
{% for block in entry.body %}

    {% set fields = block.getFieldLayout().getFields() %}

    <ul>
        <li>{{ block.getType().name }}
        <ul>
            {% for field in fields %}
                <li>{{ field.getField().name }}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want to output label of field, not value of field.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.  Updated answer.